# Creating and updating a plot using a QPushButton in PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I am pretty new to PyQt5. I would like to have a button that, when clicked, generates and shows a plot. I cannot seem to find a way to use the QPushButton to call the `PlotCanvas` function successfully.

```
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, Qt
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
    import random
    import numpy as np
    import math

    class GUI_Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):

        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):
            self.plot_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.plot_button.setText('Plot')
            self.plot_button.setToolTip('Plots the function')
            self.plot_button.move(50,240)

            self.plot_button.clicked.connect(self.updater)

       def updater(self):
           PlotCanvas(self, inputparam=5)
           print('Function has been called.')
```

The code above does not work (`PlotCanvas` doesn't plot) even though I receive the 'function has been called' printout.

However if I simply call `PlotCanvas` in `initUI`, it plots it as expected.

```
    def initUI(self):
        self.plot_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.plot_button.setText('Plot')
        self.plot_button.setToolTip('Plots the function')
        self.plot_button.move(50,240)

        self.plot_button.clicked.connect(self.updater)
        PlotCanvas(self, inputparam=5)
```

The above code plots the function as expected.

Furthermore, if I simply call the `updater` function without the pushbutton (shown below), the plot is shown.

```
    def initUI(self):
        self.plot_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.plot_button.setText('Plot')
        self.plot_button.setToolTip('Plots the function')
        self.plot_button.move(50,240)

        #self.plot_button.clicked.connect(self.updater)
        self.updater()

   def updater(self):
       PlotCanvas(self, inputparam=5)
       print('Function has been called.')
```

I sense I do not know how 'self' works and by passing a clicked signal I am somehow messing things up. Any help/insight would be appreciated.

```
    class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas):

        def __init__(self, parent=None, width=1.5, height=2, dpi=100, inputparam=0):
            fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
            self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

            FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
            self.setParent(parent)


            self.LLA_Plotter(inputparam)
# This function performs calculations and outputs x,y data points to plot



            ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
            for i in range(0,90):
                ax.scatter(x[i], y[i], color='b', s=0.6)
                ax.set_title('testing plot')
            plt.show()
```

Comment: what is `self.calculate_button` ?

Comment: It was actually supposed to be `self.plot_button` . I edited the code before posting it here to make it more "readable" but forgot to change that line. The changes have been edited.